# Apache Camel jms ack message delivery notification

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms

Looking for possibility to get `camel` `jms` ack delivery notification.
So - I want to notify producer when message is delivered on server (not when consumer is received).

Possible solution:

```
CompletableFuture<Exchange> future =  template.asyncSend(uri, exchange, synchronisation);
```

In this case synchronisation `onComplete` method triggered when consumer received.
The same with `future` get.

I want to detect moment when message is delivered on `jms` server and if it is delivered.

Thank you